# Facing issues in starting the iTorch Kernel

Tags: linux, lua, jupyter-notebook, torch

Whenever I start the iTorch Kernel, it dies and shows the following the error. I have installed the 'lmzq' but it is still asking about it.

```
[I 04:17:34.860 NotebookApp] Kernel started: fdf63071-81e7-401e-ad6a-b5b343fcc3fb
/home/abdul/torch/install/bin/luajit: error loading module 'lzmq' from file '/home/abdul/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/lzmq.so':
libzmq.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
[C]: at 0x0047aff0
[C]: in function 'require'
/home/abdul/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:11: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
(command line):1: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x00406670
Torch 7.0 Copyright (C) 2001-2011 Idiap, NEC Labs, NYU
/home/abdul/torch/install/bin/luajit: error loading module 'lzmq' from file '/home/abdul/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/lzmq.so':
libzmq.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
[C]: at 0x0047aff0
[C]: in function 'require'
...e/abdul/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/IOHandler.lua:12: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
(command line):1: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x00406670
```

Comment: Check whether lzmq is available in the path it mentions: `/home/abdul/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/lzmq.so`

Comment: Seems it can not find libzmq, not lzmq.

Comment: @hjpotter92 it is available there.

Comment: @moteus After your comment, I installed **libzmq-dev** though it removed a file called **libzmq3-dev** which seems to be working as alternate. Even after all these, no success at all and got the same error again.

Comment: I am not sure how linux system do search dynamic deps. But on my Debian system I just install `apt-get install libzmq3 libzmq3-dev` and then `luarocks intall lzmq` and all seems works. `libzmq.so.3` placed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory. apt list display `libzmq3/stable,stable,now 4.0.5+dfsg-2+deb8u1 amd64 [installed]` and `libzmq3-dev/stable,stable,now 4.0.5+dfsg-2+deb8u1 amd64 [installed]`

Comment: Also `libzmq` seems version 2. `lzmq` does not work with this version. May be you do not install `libzmq3` package?

Comment: There is _residual-config_ written after the libzmq3 name though don;'t know what does it mean.

`libzmq-dev/xenial 2.2.0+dfsg-7 amd64
libzmq-java/xenial 3.1.0-10 amd64
libzmq-java-doc/xenial,xenial 3.1.0-10 all
libzmq-jni/xenial 3.1.0-10 amd64
libzmq1/xenial 2.2.0+dfsg-7 amd64
libzmq3/now 4.0.4+dfsg-2 amd64 [residual-config]
libzmq3-dev/xenial,now 4.1.4-7 amd64 [installed]
libzmq5/xenial,now 4.1.4-7 amd64 [installed]
libzmq5-dbg/xenial 4.1.4-7 amd64
libzmqpp-dev/xenial 3.2.0-0ubuntu4 amd64
libzmqpp3/xenial 3.2.0-0ubuntu4 amd64`

Comment: The issue has been resolved. `luarocks install lmzq` worked now which was not working before. It seems installing the torch and its dependencies installed some missing files. Thanks for your precious time.